# GraphDB owl:equivalentClass infrencing not working. Protege reasoner is able to infer this

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, graphdb

I created below ontology using protege and imported exactly into GraphDB.

I've 1 individual "HxH" which is of type "comic" and has country "Japan". I've defined "Manga" as owl:equivalentClass to "comic + Japan".

When I run reasoner **in protege it is able to infer that HxH is of type Manga**. GraphDB doesn't infer this. It only display explicit triples both in query result and graph overview tab.

*Image from Protege :* [Protege is able to infer that HxH is of type Manga (yellow highlights)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD22j.png)

*Sparql query (in graphDB) :*

```
PREFIX : <http://www.comic.org/o-1#>
select * where { 
    :HxH?p ?o .
} limit 100
```

*Result of above query :*

|  | p | o |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rdf:type | :Comic |
| 2 | rdf:type | owl:NamedIndividual |
| 3 | :hasCountryOfOrigin | :Japan |

GraphDB **couldn't infer** HxH is of type Manga.

*Ontology I created (Turtle syntax) :*

```
@prefix : <http://www.comic.org/o-1#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.comic.org/o-1> .

<http://www.comic.org/o-1> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.comic.org/o-1#hasCountryOfOrigin
:hasCountryOfOrigin rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                             owl:FunctionalProperty ;
                    rdfs:domain :Comic ;
                    rdfs:range :Country .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.comic.org/o-1#Comic
:Comic rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:disjointWith :Country .


###  http://www.comic.org/o-1#Country
:Country rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.comic.org/o-1#Manga
:Manga rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Comic
                                                  [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                    owl:onProperty :hasCountryOfOrigin ;
                                                    owl:hasValue :Japan
                                                  ]
                                                ) ;
                             rdf:type owl:Class
                           ] .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.comic.org/o-1#HxH
:HxH rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
              :Comic ;
     :hasCountryOfOrigin :Japan .


###  http://www.comic.org/o-1#Japan
:Japan rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :Country .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: Protege does make use of full OWL DL reasoners like Pellet or HermiT. GraphDB doesn't have such a reasoner - which ruleset did you use? I mean, it has to cover equivalence, intersection in superclass and hasValue constraints.

Comment: @UninformedUser I used RDFS-Plus(optimized) rule set. [Reading from here RDFS-Plus does cover equivalence.](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/RDFS-Plus#owl:equivalentClass:_Equivalence) Not sure about other two. 

I'll try runing new database with different rule set and edit this commet if it works.

Comment: Edit : Ruleset - OWL-Max is working. Wrong ruleset was the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

- the problem was when we create a new DB instance in GraphDB it set "Ruleset = RDF-Plus" by default.
- Changing this to "OWL-Max" or any other rule set that support equivalence, intersection and hasValue should do the job.